# Passing a list of objects to controller with Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to export a table of data that can contain thousands of lines into a csv file.
my problem is that i cannot pass the ArrayList that contains this data back to the controller.
I'm using Spring MVC 3

i don't want to put an input text in each field on the table and submit the form.
that could cause a problem because of the volume of data.

the data of the table is in an object. can i simply pass this object back to the controller?

```
<div class="row">
        <c:if test="${not empty listeResp}">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>NUMERO DE SERIE GSM/CDMA</th>
                    <th>MSISDN</th>
                    <th>DATE UTILISATION</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${listeResp}" var="resp">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${resp.getSerialGSM()}</td>
                            <td>${resp.getMsisdn()}</td>
                            <td>${resp.getUse_date()}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </c:if>
    </div>
```

can i passe the object listeResp to the controller so i can export it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that i put the arrayList Object into **session** before i pass it to view, then when i want to export the table showed in view, i just retrieve the object from **session** and export it.
it was a logical solution more than a technical one.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is do your entire logical in the frontend. Save each changes in a localStorage or in a javascript variable and in the save/finish/send button, send to backend everything. Group it in a javascript object and send to backend in the same format.

```
// the father received in the Controller
ObjectJavaScript
// your listResp is a list entity inside the object above
List<ListResp>
```